# gitlab-runner configuration not showing in config.toml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, config, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-runner

I have a simple question
I'm hosting a GitLab server and when I want to register a new runner it's successfully created but when I go to :

> ~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml

this `config.toml` file doesn't show me, my new configuration runner. it just shows my older runners.
It's something like this for my other runners:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "minoemix-superadmin"
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:19.03.12"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/certs/client","/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Does anyone know why? I need my new runner configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as mentioned in [Advanced configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html), check if another file is modified instead:

> You can find the `config.toml` file in:
>
> - `/etc/gitlab-runner/` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as root (this is also the path for service configuration)
> - `~/.gitlab-runner/` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as non-root
> - `./` on other systems

So it depends on your OS and on how you have launched GitLab (as root, or as a user account).

Second, as in [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4738), check if you have done a `gitlab-runner register` which should trigger `Merging configuration from template file...`: it shows which `config.toml` file it updates.